# Showing a stochastic process is a Pure Jump Markov Process

Tags: conditional-probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

> Suppose that $T$ is an exponential random variable. Show that the
>   process ${X_T (t)}:=1_{[T,\infty)}(t), t\geq0,$ with state space
>   $S=\{0,1\}$ is a Pure Jump Markov Process.

Here is what I have gotten so far:

Let $T\sim\mathrm{Expo}  (q)$, where $q>0$. Then, we can write the sample path decomposition:
$${X_T (t)}= 1_{[T,\infty)}(t)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             1  & t\geq T,\\
             \\ 0 & t<T . 
             \end{array}
   \right.$$

The process is a jump process since the $t \in [0,\infty),$ the state space is $S=\{0,1\}$ (which is clearly countable), and the sample path is right continuous.

Now, here is where I get confused. How do I show that this process is a PJMP? This is what I have tried:

Consider
$$\mathbb{P}({X_T (t+s)=0|{X_T (t)}=0)}$$
$$= \mathbb{P}({1_{[T,\infty)} (t+s)=0|{1_{[T,\infty)} (t)}=0)}$$ $$=\mathbb{P}(T>t+s|\ T>t) = \mathbb{P}(T>s)$$
$$\mathbb{P}({X_T (s)=0|{X_T (0)}=0)}$$

which I have used the memoryless property of the exponential distribution. But I am sure that the above haven't actually proved the Markovian property for a pure jump process.